# Validation of an email in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I implemented the following code. It is accepting any type of mail id's. Example: abc@xyz.com. But I want to accept the perfect mail id's.Example :abc@gmail.com,abc@yahoo.com. Can any one guide how to do this.

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error gives in this code

Comment: Do you mean you only want to accept emails addresses that are from valid email domains?

Comment: yes i want to accept the valid email addresses

Comment: The only way to do that is to take the email address that is entered and then go off and query the email server on the domain that they provided. You will have no way of knowing all of the valid domains otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
    
    BOOL result = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
    if(result)
    {
        NSSet *domains= [NSSet setWithObjects:@"yahoo.com",@"yahoo.co.in",@"yahoo.co.au",@"yahoo.co.nz",@"gmail.com",@"rediffmail.com",.........., nil];
        NSArray *arrayObjects = [domains allObjects];
        BOOL results = NO;
              for(int i = 0;i<[arrayObjects count];i++)
              {
                  if([emailTest rangeOfString:[arrayObjects objectAtIndex:i]].location != NSNotFound)
                  {
                      results = YES;
                      break;
                  }
              }
          return results;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    } 
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Comment: This would mean you would have to list EVERY domain on the internet plus you would have to update your app every time a new domain was registered. Not everyone uses gmail, yahoo mail, etc.

Comment: @NickBull: Yeah I know this is not very feasible but still if siva wants it for only some number of domains then it would work for him. As such the whole requirement itself is very different and I would say not possible but if it is for only some predefined domains then this could be an easy way out.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: ADDED THE DOMAIN NAME CHECK**

The below will check for domain names and the extension too, Feel free to add your required names in this code.

```
     - (BOOL)isValidEmail:(NSString *)inputText
        {
            NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z][A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]*@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"; 
            NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
            NSRange dotRange;
            NSRange atRange;

            BOOL isValidDomain = NO;
            BOOL isValidSite = NO;

            if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:inputText]) 
            {
                dotRange = [inputText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputText length])];
                int indexOfDot = dotRange.location;

                if(dotRange.location != NSNotFound) 
                {
                    NSString *topLevelDomain = [inputText substringFromIndex:indexOfDot];
                    topLevelDomain = [topLevelDomain lowercaseString];
                    NSSet *TLD;
                    TLD = [NSSet setWithObjects:@".aero", @".asia", @".biz", @".cat", @".com", @".coop", @".edu", @".gov", @".info", @".int", @".jobs", @".mil", @".mobi", @".museum", @".name", @".net", @".org", @".pro", @".tel", @".travel", @".ac", @".ad", @".ae", @".af", @".ag", @".ai", @".al", @".am", @".an", @".ao", @".aq", @".ar", @".as", @".at", @".au", @".aw", @".ax", @".az", @".ba", @".bb", @".bd", @".be", @".bf", @".bg", @".bh", @".bi", @".bj", @".bm", @".bn", @".bo", @".br", @".bs", @".bt", @".bv", @".bw", @".by", @".bz", @".ca", @".cc", @".cd", @".cf", @".cg", @".ch", @".ci", @".ck", @".cl", @".cm", @".cn", @".co", @".cr", @".cu", @".cv", @".cx", @".cy", @".cz", @".de", @".dj", @".dk", @".dm", @".do", @".dz", @".ec", @".ee", @".eg", @".er", @".es", @".et", @".eu", @".fi", @".fj", @".fk", @".fm", @".fo", @".fr", @".ga", @".gb", @".gd", @".ge", @".gf", @".gg", @".gh", @".gi", @".gl", @".gm", @".gn", @".gp", @".gq", @".gr", @".gs", @".gt", @".gu", @".gw", @".gy", @".hk", @".hm", @".hn", @".hr", @".ht", @".hu", @".id", @".ie", @" No", @".il", @".im", @".in", @".io", @".iq", @".ir", @".is", @".it", @".je", @".jm", @".jo", @".jp", @".ke", @".kg", @".kh", @".ki", @".km", @".kn", @".kp", @".kr", @".kw", @".ky", @".kz", @".la", @".lb", @".lc", @".li", @".lk", @".lr", @".ls", @".lt", @".lu", @".lv", @".ly", @".ma", @".mc", @".md", @".me", @".mg", @".mh", @".mk", @".ml", @".mm", @".mn", @".mo", @".mp", @".mq", @".mr", @".ms", @".mt", @".mu", @".mv", @".mw", @".mx", @".my", @".mz", @".na", @".nc", @".ne", @".nf", @".ng", @".ni", @".nl", @".no", @".np", @".nr", @".nu", @".nz", @".om", @".pa", @".pe", @".pf", @".pg", @".ph", @".pk", @".pl", @".pm", @".pn", @".pr", @".ps", @".pt", @".pw", @".py", @".qa", @".re", @".ro", @".rs", @".ru", @".rw", @".sa", @".sb", @".sc", @".sd", @".se", @".sg", @".sh", @".si", @".sj", @".sk", @".sl", @".sm", @".sn", @".so", @".sr", @".st", @".su", @".sv", @".sy", @".sz", @".tc", @".td", @".tf", @".tg", @".th", @".tj", @".tk", @".tl", @".tm", @".tn", @".to", @".tp", @".tr", @".tt", @".tv", @".tw", @".tz", @".ua", @".ug", @".uk", @".us", @".uy", @".uz", @".va", @".vc", @".ve", @".vg", @".vi", @".vn", @".vu", @".wf", @".ws", @".ye", @".yt", @".za", @".zm", @".zw", nil];
                    if(topLevelDomain != nil && ([TLD containsObject:topLevelDomain])) 
                    {
                        isValidDomain = YES;
                    }
                }
                atRange = [inputText rangeOfString:@"@" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputText length])];
                int indexOfAt = atRange.location;

                if(atRange.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSString *topLevelSite = [inputText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexOfAt, indexOfDot - indexOfAt)];
                    topLevelSite = [topLevelSite lowercaseString];
                    NSSet *TLS;
//Add your required domain names to the set below
                    TLS = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"@google", @"@yahoo", nil];
                    if(topLevelSite != nil && ([TLS containsObject:topLevelSite])) 
                    {
                        isValidSite = YES;
                    }
                }

            }
            return (isValidDomain && isValidSite);
        }
```

Comment: It is working good. But if i given cc@cc.com then it is not responding any thing. So how can i over come this

Comment: Writing your own REGEX will probably be faster than trying to understand someone else's.

Comment: @siva I have updated my answer for your requirement. Check now.